# Could not successfully network Frontend and API App Service by using private endpoints and VNet integration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have these subnets under my virtual network

- **outbound-subnet**
- **inbound-subnet**

On one of my App Service (API) I enabled the Private endpoints using the **inbound-subnet** in the Networking Tab > Inbound Traffic so I can restrict the access of it via the internet.

And on my other App Service (Frontend) I enabled the VNet integration using the **outbound-subnet** in the Network Tab > Outbound Traffic.

My main goal here is to expose the App Service (Frontend) on the internet and only allow the App Service (API) to be called by the App Service (Frontend).

After configuring all of these settings I was able to achieve the following

1. The App Service (API) is not accessible via the internet anymore
2. The App Service (Frontend) is still accessible on the internet

The problem that I am encountering right now is that the App Service (Frontend) could not call the API endpoints of the App Service (API) and I am getting the error of

> 403 Ip Forbidden

I don't know what is wrong with my configuration and I am fairly new to Azure I hope anyone could guide me on how I can do this. Thank you!

Edit:

For additional information, I am using the App Service Plan Production P1V2 SKU/Pricing Tier.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below.***

I have created one app service with Private endpoints inbound subnet and another app service for vnet integration outbound subnet.

When I access the URL, I got the same error as below

[image]

Try to access private endpoint via application gateway I added both app service as backend pool like below:

[image]

Try to add backend setting and healthy probe and create a virtual machine like below:

[image]

Create a bastion to connect securely to the virtual machine for testing the private endpoint. When I connect with bastion I got result successfully like below.

Run PowerShell or cmd Enter `nslookup <webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net`.

[image]

[image]

***Reference:***

[Tutorial: Connect to a web app using an Azure Private endpoint - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-webapp-portal)

Comment: I am sorry that maybe you got confused with the requirements. What I am trying to do doesn't involve accessing the App Services via Azure Virtual Machines.

The requirements are something like this:

1. App Service (Frontend) should be accessible on the internet, not Azure VM only.
2. App Service (API Backend) should only be accessible by the App Service (Frontend) and not be exposed on the internet.

Comment: With that requirements, what I have successfully done is that the `App Service (Frontend)` is already accessible on the internet but it cannot access the `App Service (API Backend)`. The networking I've done is on the `App Service (Frontend)` I set up an `Outbound Traffic VNet Integration` using `subnetA` and on the `App Service (API Backend)` I set up the `Inbound Traffic Private endpoint` using `subnetB` both of the `subnetA` and `subnetB` are using the same VNET.

Comment: the posted answer does not answer the question.